# OpenCV4.2 and Ubuntu16.04 with python2.7?

Tags: ros, python, opencv

**Summary:**

I'm using new vision of opencv, opencv 4.2 with ubuntu 16.04 and python 2.7

After built `cv_bridge`, the output is:

```
import rospkg
ImportError: No module named rospkg
```

---

**Here's the more detailed version:** [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues/272)

I tried to build cv_bridge in order to run OpenCV 4.2, Ubuntu 16.04 (ROS Kinetic) and python 2.7.

I will explain what I do for that.

I built it before with OpenCV 3.3.1 in order to use GPU and it was very fine and it is still working now. To best my knowledge, there is `ros-kinetic-opencv3`, it is working only on CPU. I removed it using `sudo apt remove ros-kinetic-opencv3`

After removing, I just downloaded your here and put in my `~/catkin_ws/src/`, then making `~/catkin_ws/catkin_make` on my PC without any modifications. I think that I was lucky.

Now, I'd like use some advantage of OpenCV 4.2 that is not with older versions like OpenCV 3.3.1. Meanwhile, I can't update robot's system, it is Ubuntu 16.04.

So, I tried to build `cv_bridge`, all modifications as following:

I copied and pasted `module_opencv3.cpp`, then change its name to `module_opencv4.cpp` so that became three models 4, 3 and 2.cpp instead of two 3 and 2.cpp.

Next , Sreevan mentioned [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues/272#issuecomment-471311300) some changes, I did like Sreevan:

In `cv_bridge/src/module_opencv3.cpp` change signature of two functions

3.1) `UMatData* allocate(int dims0, const int* sizes, int type, void* data, size_t* step, int flags, UMatUsageFlags usageFlags) const`
to
`UMatData* allocate(int dims0, const int* sizes, int type, void* data, size_t* step, AccessFlag flags, UMatUsageFlags usageFlags) const`

3.2) `bool allocate(UMatData* u, int accessFlags, UMatUsageFlags usageFlags) const`
to
`bool allocate(UMatData* u, AccessFlag accessFlags, UMatUsageFlags usageFlags) const`

Next, I went to this file `~/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge$ CMakeLists.txt` and change it as:
from:

```
find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS
    opencv_core
    opencv_imgproc
    opencv_imgcodecs
  PATHS /usr/local
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH
  CONFIG
)
```

to:

```
if ( NOT (OpenCV_VERSION_MAJOR VERSION_LESS 4) )
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS
    opencv_core
    opencv_imgproc
    opencv_imgcodecs
  #PATHS /usr/local/include
  PATHS /usr/local
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH
  CONFIG
)
else()
find_package(OpenCV 3 REQUIRED
  COMPONENTS
    opencv_core
    opencv_imgproc
    opencv_imgcodecs
  PATHS /usr/local
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH
  CONFIG
)
endif()
```

Next, I went to this file `~/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src$ CMakeLists.txt` and change it as:
from:

```
if (OpenCV_VERSION_MAJOR VERSION_EQUAL 3)
  add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_boost module.cpp module_opencv3.cpp)
else()
  add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_boost module.cpp module_opencv2.cpp)
endif()
```

to

```
if (OpenCV_VERSION_MAJOR VERSION_EQUAL 4)
  add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_boost module.cpp module_opencv4.cpp)
elseif(OpenCV_VERSION_MAJOR VERSION_EQUAL 3)
  add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_boost module.cpp module_opencv3.cpp)
else()
  add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_boost module.cpp module_opencv2.cpp)
endif()
```

Next, I think this step is not important, I went to this file `~/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge$ package.xml` and change any `opencv3` to `opencv4`

Finally, `~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make`

everything was ok but when I run the code:

```
import rospy
import cv2
import numpy as np
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError

print(cv2.__version__)

class CVControl:
  def __init__(self):
    self.bridge = CvBridge()
    self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_raw", Image, self.img_callback)
  def img_callback(self, data):
    try:
      cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(data, "bgr8")
    except CvBridgeError as e:
      print e

    frame = cv_image
    cv2.imshow("Image window", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(3)
def main():
  ctrl = CVControl()
  rospy.init_node('image_converter')
  try:
    rospy.spin()

  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Shutting down"
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

It runs by OpenCV 3.3.1

If I need to run it by OpenCV 4.2
I added those lines in first the code:

```
import sys
ros_path2 = '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
ros_path3 = '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'
if  ros_path2 and ros_path3 in sys.path:
  sys.path.remove(ros_path2)
  sys.path.remove(ros_path3)
```

The output is:

```
import rospkg
ImportError: No module named rospkg
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. It would install `rospkg` to your computer. (I have faced this issue too in the past, and this would most likely solve it)

`sudo apt-get install python-rospkg`

Comment: No, this command will install  ros-kinetic-opencv3 that it runs on CPU.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? If yes, then use `pip install python-rospkg` to install this to the end. This would ensure `rospkg`, `ros`, `opencv` all use the same python installation.

Answer (score 0):

[Python 2.7 has been sunsetted](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

From the official documentation:

> **What will happen if I did not upgrade by January 1st, 2020?**
>
> If people find catastrophic security problems in Python 2, or in software written in Python 2, then most volunteers will not help fix them. **If you need help with Python 2 software, then many volunteers will not help you, and over time fewer and fewer volunteers will be able to help you.** You will lose chances to use good tools because they will only run on Python 3, and you will slow down people who depend on you and work with you.
>
> Some of these problems started on January 1. Other problems will grow over time.

(emphasis added)

Comment: Thanks for your  advice, I know that but I have to use it few months until finish my current work. The main issue for this question is between OpenCV 3 and 4.

Comment: @Redhwan - You say that, but the error appears to be about ROS. What does ROS have to do with this? In your other post you stated, `I removed [ROS] using sudo apt remove ros-kinetic-opencv3` - so, you removed ROS, and now you're getting an error that ROS doesn't exist... I'm not sure what you expected is going to happen or what this has to do with OpenCV.

Comment: @ Chuck-the main idea is ROS  has a OpenCV version, for example,  Ubuntu 16.04 ...> kinetic .....>opencv3.3.1 and  Ubuntu 18.04 ...> Melodic.....>opencv3.x and so on. You can see here http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions. So, if we need to use the O-penCV version is independent on ROS, we need to build a cv_bridge that compiles new OpenCV with ROS. ROS has many libraries and OpenCV is one of them.

Comment: @Redhwan - I understand you need to build a bridge, but what I'm saying is that it looks like you're having a **ROS** issue, notably that rospkg is not installed, and not an OpenCV issue.

Comment: @ Chuck--when we install ROS, we install  rospkg, ros-xxxxxx-opencv, cv_bridge,.... but we remove ros-xxxxxx-opencv that also removes   rospkg and cv_bridge in order to use a different OpenCV version. The issue is incompatibility.

Comment: @Redhwan - Maybe it's me. I don't understand what's happening. You're telling me you `also removes rospkg`, and your error is `No module named rospkg`, but you think it's a compatability issue. I'm saying I think you've removed rospkg and now it *doesn't exist to be imported.* Whether or not they're compatible is a completely different question. You haven't posted any errors about compatibility - you posted asking why you can't import rospkg. It doesn't exist.

Comment: If you install it and you get some errors, maybe someone else can help you by evaluating what those other errors are, but for now I think [this answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/20762/9720) is probably the best you're going to get - *install rospkg.* You [made the comment](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/20761/opencv4-2-and-ubuntu16-04-with-python2-7/20768?noredirect=1#comment34072_20762) that it'll install ros-kinetic-opencv3, but I can't find any support for that statement when I [look at the source code](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rospkg).